# Why does the /run directory have inode 2?

Tags: inode

It's well known that the `/` directory has inode number 2 (see also [Why does '/' have the inode 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198673/85039)). And we also know that hard links share the same inode number. So far so good.

Here's the confusing bit (notice the `Inode:` part):

```
$ stat /run
  File: /run
  Size: 940         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 16h/22d Inode: 2           Links: 32
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-09-10 10:22:18.198727482 +0800
Modify: 2018-09-10 02:47:58.655999930 +0800
Change: 2018-09-10 02:47:58.655999930 +0800
 Birth: -
```

The simple question is "Why do they have the same inode?" The `/run` directory is different from `/` and `/run` is not hardlink to `/`.

Comment: The base directory of any Ext2/3/4 file system uses inode 2 (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/408192/86440)). However `/run` is usually a `tmpfs` and that rule doesn’t apply — what does `mount | grep 'on /run '` output?

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks for finding that. So essentially it's because /run is root directory since it's a virtual filesystem.

Comment: Essentially yes, but that doesn’t explain everything because [`tmpfs` file systems don’t have a fixed root inode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4411701/4500798).

Comment: For me it's `Inode: 14511` and it's `tmpfs`.  `/` is inode 2 though (ext4). `/tmp` is tmpfs and inode 2860. Fedora 25 dom0 under Qubes OS 4.0